# Laravel nested passport scopes routing, does not reach nested route method

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-passport

I have yet to solve this so far.

So here I have a

#### Route group

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersController;

Route::group( ['prefix' => 'user','middleware' => ['
    auth:user-api','scopes:user'] ],function(){
//Below: tried both scopes/scope for this route 
//I also tried to remove the auth middleware, but then fail to route because of the scope middleware requiring the auth (as far as I understand)
    Route::post('create',[UsersController::class,'store'])->middleware(['auth:user-api', 'scopes:User_Create']);
});
```

#### My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(["message"=>"here"]);
    }
}
```

#### Route List

```
|        | POST      | api/user/create                         |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@store                                | api                |
                  |  |                                         |                                   |                                                                           |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           |        auth:user-api     |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | scopes:user        |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | auth:user-api      |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | scopes:User_Create |
|
```

#### App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider->boot()

```
Passport::routes();
Passport::tokensCan([
   //User Tokens
   'User_Create' => 'Create User',
   'user' => 'User Type'
]);
```

#### Guards: config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'user-api'=>[
            'driver'=>'passport',
            'provider'=>'users',
            'hash'=>false,
        ],
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
        'customer-api'=>[
            'driver'=>'passport',
            'provider'=>'customers',
            'hash'=>false,
        ],

    ],
```

My user is authenticated with the correct token scopes.
Problem is when I am accessing the route;
It doesn't output the expected message, instead, it returns html with what seems to be an object.

#### Route Output : localhost:8000/api/user/create

Here's the output from my postman (the Accept header is set to: application/json).

```
<script>
    Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact, .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse, .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; }'; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); refStyle = doc.createElement('style'); (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e, n) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else { n = /\bsf-dump-ellipsis\b/.test(e.target.className) ? e.target.parentNode : e.target; if ((n = n.nextElementSibling) && 'A' == n.tagName) { if (!/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(n.className)) { n = n.nextElementSibling || n; } f(n, e, true); } } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += elt.className == 'sf-dump-compact' ? '<span>&#9654;</span>' : '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(), currentRect, searchRect; if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); if ('scrollIntoView' in currentNode) { currentNode.scrollIntoView(true); currentRect = currentNode.getBoundingClientRect(); searchRect = search.getBoundingClientRect(); if (currentRect.top < (searchRect.top + searchRect.height)) { window.scrollBy(0, -(searchRect.top + searchRect.height + 5)); } } } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="sf-dump-search-input"> <span class="sf-dump-search-count">0 of 0<\/span> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-previous" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 1331l-166 165q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L896 965l-531 531q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-165q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l742-741q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 741q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-next" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 808l-742 741q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L109 808q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l166-165q19-19 45-19t45 19l531 531 531-531q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 165q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer = 0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput, 'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root); resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) { counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var classMatches = [ "sf-dump-str", "sf-dump-key", "sf-dump-public", "sf-dump-protected", "sf-dump-private", ].map(xpathHasClass).join(' or '); var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('.//span[' + classMatches + '][contains(translate(child::text(), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toUpperCase()) + ', ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + '), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + ')]', root, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state); }, 400); }); Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next, .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) { addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1 !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() : state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function (e) { var isSearchActive = !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 === e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) { /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ if (70 === e.keyCode && document.activeElement === searchInput) { /* * If CMD/CTRL + F is hit while having focus on search input, * the user probably meant to trigger browser search instead. * Let the browser execute its behavior: */ return; } e.preventDefault(); search.className = search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, ''); searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 === e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += ' sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault(); resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if ( (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 === e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) { e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = '<span class=sf-dump-str-collapse>'+h+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="Collapse"> &#9664;</a></span>'+ '<span class=sf-dump-str-expand>'+elt.innerHTML+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="'+x+' remaining characters"> &#9654;</a></span>'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document); 
</script>
<style>
    pre.sf-dump {
        display: block;
        white-space: pre;
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: initial !important;
    }

    pre.sf-dump:after {
        content: "";
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
    }

    pre.sf-dump span {
        display: inline;
    }

    pre.sf-dump a {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        color: inherit;
    }

    pre.sf-dump img {
        max-width: 50em;
        max-height: 50em;
        margin: .5em 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAAAAAA6mKC9AAAAHUlEQVQY02O8zAABilCaiQEN0EeA8QuUcX9g3QEAAjcC5piyhyEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) #D3D3D3;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: visible;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        max-width: 5em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis {
        max-width: none;
    }

    pre.sf-dump code {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0;
        background: none;
    }

    .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight {
        background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3);
        border: 1px solid #7DA0B1;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active {
        background: rgba(253, 175, 0, 0.4);
        border: 1px solid #ffa500;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden {
        display: none !important;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper {
        font-size: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        display: flex;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 5px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>* {
        vertical-align: top;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 21px;
        font-weight: normal;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #FFF;
        color: #757575;
        border: 1px solid #BBB;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>input.sf-dump-search-input {
        padding: 3px;
        height: 21px;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-right: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        color: #000;
        min-width: 15px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-next,
    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-previous {
        background: #F2F2F2;
        outline: none;
        border-left: none;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-next {
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-next>svg,
    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-previous>svg {
        pointer-events: none;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-count {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px;
        margin: 0;
        border-left: none;
        line-height: 21px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump,
    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default {
        background-color: #18171B;
        color: #FF8400;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font: 12px Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99999;
        word-break: break-all
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #1299DA
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const {
        font-weight: bold
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #56DB3A
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note {
        color: #1299DA
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref {
        color: #A0A0A0
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public {
        color: #FFFFFF
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected {
        color: #FFFFFF
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private {
        color: #FFFFFF
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta {
        color: #B729D9
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key {
        color: #56DB3A
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index {
        color: #1299DA
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis {
        color: #FF8400
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ns {
        user-select: none;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis-note {
        color: #1299DA
    }
</style>
<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-2042796111 data-indent-pad="  "><span class=sf-dump-note>Laravel\Passport\Token</span> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#1253</a><samp data-depth=1 class=sf-dump-expanded>
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">table</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">oauth_access_tokens</span>"
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">keyType</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="6 characters">string</span>"
  +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">incrementing</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">guarded</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">casts</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:2</span> [<samp data-depth=2 class=sf-dump-compact>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>scopes</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="5 characters">array</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>revoked</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">bool</span>"
  </samp>]
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dates</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:1</span> [<samp data-depth=2 class=sf-dump-compact>
    <span class=sf-dump-index>0</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="10 characters">expires_at</span>"
  </samp>]
  +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">timestamps</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">connection</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="5 characters">mysql</span>"
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">primaryKey</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="2 characters">id</span>"
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">with</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">withCount</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">perPage</span>: <span class=sf-dump-num>15</span>
  +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">exists</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>true</span>
  +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">wasRecentlyCreated</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">attributes</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:9</span> [<samp data-depth=2 class=sf-dump-compact>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="80 characters">56518626bb17f603ce7dbdfdd91fb9330d30ed74c65e7ce6d5384dffc124e77fd1cdc28040426ccf</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>user_id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>19</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>client_id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>15</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="16 characters">SuperAdmin token</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>scopes</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>revoked</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>0</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>created_at</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">2021-02-22 00:08:49</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>updated_at</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">2021-02-22 00:08:49</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>expires_at</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">2022-02-22 00:08:49</span>"
  </samp>]
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">original</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:9</span> [<samp data-depth=2 class=sf-dump-compact>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="80 characters">56518626bb17f603ce7dbdfdd91fb9330d30ed74c65e7ce6d5384dffc124e77fd1cdc28040426ccf</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>user_id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>19</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>client_id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>15</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="16 characters">SuperAdmin token</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>scopes</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>revoked</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>0</span>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>created_at</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">2021-02-22 00:08:49</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>updated_at</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">2021-02-22 00:08:49</span>"
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>expires_at</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="19 characters">2022-02-22 00:08:49</span>"
  </samp>]
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">changes</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:1</span> [<samp data-depth=2 class=sf-dump-compact>
    "<span class=sf-dump-key>scopes</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
  </samp>]
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">classCastCache</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dateFormat</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">appends</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dispatchesEvents</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">observables</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">relations</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">touches</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">hidden</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">visible</span>: []
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">fillable</span>: []
</samp>}
</pre>
<script>
    Sfdump("sf-dump-2042796111")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed how I am calling the controller method,

I am calling it this way

```
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'user','middleware' => ['auth:user-api','scopes:user'] ],function(){

   // authenticated staff routes here 
    Route::post('create',[\App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['scope:User_Create']);
});
```

And I removed the namespace for my route, located at \App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider

```
 Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api/user.php'));
```

The route method is now executing

Comment: It was a weird behavior that I can't understand. If someone can, please do make sure to tell me.